# Is there a symbol to concatenate strings into one character scalar in APL?

Tags: apl

I'm new to APL and am aware that the `,` (catenate) function will catenate character vectors,
and thus assigning `I` as the following :

```
      I←'hello','world'
```

will result in `I` being equal to

```
hello world
```

And each word can be indexed independently. I would like to convert this character vector of two parts to a simple string that is "hello world" (I believe scalar is the proper terminology) so I can store the entire string into an element of a matrix.

Let `A` be a matrix:

```
      A[1;1]←I
```

Currently the line above gives a Domain error, as trying to assign a vector to a scalar doesn't work. How might I reconcile this?

Comment: `'hello','world'` gives a 10-element vector `'helloworld'` without space.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://abrudz.github.io/lb/apl) bookmarklet which allows you to type APL characters like `←` on websites like Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you- I didn't know where to get the symbols, so thanks for making those changes for me.

Comment: Good clarification, Bubbler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [enclose function](http://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Primitive%20Functions/Enclose.htm) `⊂` which does exactly what you want, packaging any array as a scalar:

```
      A←2 3⍴⍳6
      A
1 2 3
4 5 6
      A[1;1]←⊂'hello world'
      A
┌───────────┬─┬─┐
│hello world│2│3│
├───────────┼─┼─┤
│4          │5│6│
└───────────┴─┴─┘
```

[Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=A%u21902%203%u2374%u23736%20%u22C4%20A%20%u22C4%20A%5B1%3B1%5D%u2190%u2282%27hello%20world%27%20%u22C4%20A&run)